# Sorting a Dataframe based on specified indices

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

Currently I have a `GeoDataframe` called `world` that looks something like this, where geometry represents a Point(latitude, longitude).

```
      name            geometry
0   Vatican City    POINT (12.45338654497177 41.90328217996012)
1   San Marino      POINT (12.44177015780014 43.936095834768)
2   Vaduz           POINT (9.516669472907267 47.13372377429357)
3   Luxembourg      POINT (6.130002806227083 49.61166037912108)
4   Palikir         POINT (158.1499743237623 6.916643696007725)
```

Given another Point(lat,long), I wanted to find the closest points from this dataframe to that particular point. I used the distance function to calculate the nearest points

```
world.distance(Point(9.0,49.0)).sort_values()
```

and now I have a series that looks like this

```
2        1.936475
20       2.586576
3        2.934453
158      5.016402
172      5.284416
          ...    
6      179.671568
91     182.256232
69     188.780771
126    191.351813
122    197.120844
Length: 202, dtype: float64
```

How can I get a copy of the `world` Geodataframe sorted in that same order so it looks like below? Thanks!

```
    name            geometry
2   Vaduz           POINT (9.516669472907267 47.13372377429357)
20   ....           ......................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html). Use the resulting dataframe from calculating the distance to reindex `world`:

```
world.reindex(world.distance(Point(9.0,49.0)).sort_values().index)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using `.loc` to rearrange the `DataFrame` to which ever index you like:

```
world = world.loc[world.distance(Point(9.0,49.0)).sort_values().index]
```